# All the text appears on the top between divs

Tags: html, css, position, css-float, division

I want to make the Akita Inu and Cockapoo labels just above `box-left` divs but instead most of the labels just stacked in the middle between divs. I tried to put two divs in one div like     but it didn't work.

```css
.box-left {
  clear: all;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box-right {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="label">Akita Inu</div>
  <div class="box-left"></div>
  <div class="box-right"></div>

  
  <div class="label">Cockapoo</div>
  <div class="box-left"></div>
  <div class="box-right"></div>

  <div class="label">Corgi</div>
  <div class="box-left"></div>
  <div class="box-right"></div>

  <div class="label">Shiba Inu</div>
  <div class="box-left"></div>
  <div class="box-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box-container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;

}
```

```html
 <div class="label">Akita Inu</div>
 <div class="box-container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
  
  <div class="label">Cockapoo</div>
 <div class="box-container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**If I understand what you're about to do, I think it will work very well with the style change.**

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: both` to `.box-left` to put it *below* the floated item above it. And to put the labels below the divs above them, apply the same to `.label`

```css
.label {
  clear: both;
}

.box-left {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box-right {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="label">Akita Inu</div>
<div class="box-left"></div>
<div class="box-right"></div>


<div class="label">Cockapoo</div>
<div class="box-left"></div>
<div class="box-right"></div>

<div class="label">Corgi</div>
<div class="box-left"></div>
<div class="box-right"></div>

<div class="label">Shiba Inu</div>
<div class="box-left"></div>
<div class="box-right"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use floats. They're an outdated and troublesome technique. Instead, use inline-block containers or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.box-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
}

.label {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

.box-left {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="label">Akita Inu</div>
  <div class="box-left"></div>
  <div class="box-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="label">Cockapoo</div>
  <div class="box-left"></div>
  <div class="box-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flex for this.  Floats and absolutes should generally be avoided.

```css
.label {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

.box-left,
.box-right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    <div class="label">Akita Inu</div>
    <div class="box-left"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="label">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="box-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div>
    <div class="label">Cockapoo</div>
    <div class="box-left"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="label">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="box-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```